# How do I make a certain section be completely align with each other using CSS?

Tags: html, css, mobile

I am trying to recreate this graphic by scratch using css, html and javascript thinking in  terms of mobile first. 
This is the original :
[image: Recreate Image]

This is my version
[image]

The part where I am stuck is aligning the key specs perfectly in both mobile and 1024px size. But I'm not having any luck. I am using flexbox, and I was thinking of using the direction as a way but I don't know where I should you a container div or what.
I don't want to use a framework like Bootstrap. I need to do this by scratch. Can you please me ? Thank you so much

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Convertibles</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">
        <header>
            <h1>Convertibles</h1>
            <p class="subtext">2-in-1 laptop plus tablet</p>
        </header>


        <ul class="item-list">

            <!-- Item 1 Start-->
            <li class="item item1">
                <img src="images/chromebookpro.jpg">
                <div class="item-text">
                    <h2>Google Pixelbook</h2>
                    <p class="pricing">Starting at $999</p>
                    <p>The first high performance Chromebook with Google Assistent built in. Features a four-in-one design offering laptop, tablet, tent, and entertainment modes, an all day battery with fast charging, a sleek aluminum body, and an optional pen. </p>
                    <p class="item-specs"> Key Specs</p>
                    <div class="item-text-specs">
                        <div class="item-list">
                            <p class="article">12.3" Quad HD LCD</p>
                            <p class="article">Intel processor&reg;</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item-list">
                            <p class="article">128/256/512 GB</p>
                            <p class="article">8/16 GB memory</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <!-- Item 1 End-->


            <!-- Item 2 Start-->
            <li class="item item2">
                <img src="images/chromebookpro.jpg">
                <div class="item-text">
                    <h2>Samsung Chromebook Pro</h2>
                    <p class="pricing">Starting at $549</p>
                    <p>The power of a Chromebook. The versatility of a tablet. A 360 degree rotating screen and an Intel&reg; Core&trade; M3 processor helps get things done. Write and create naturally with a built-in pen.</p>
                    <p class="item-specs"> Key Specs</p>
                    <div class="item-text-specs">
                        <div class="item-list">
                            <p class="article">12.3" Quad HD LCD</p>
                            <p class="article">Intel processor&reg;</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item-list">
                            <p class="article">32 GB eMMC</p>
                            <p class="article">1 x 4 GB memory</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <!-- Item 2 End-->

            <!-- Item 3 Start-->
            <li class="item item3">
                <img src="images/chromebookpro.jpg">
                <div class="item-text">
                    <h2>ASUS Chromebook Flip C302</h2>
                    <p class="pricing">Starting at $499</p>
                    <p>Flip between a high-performance Chromebook, a handy backlit tablet, and anything in between with a 360 degree hinge.</p>
                    <p class="item-specs"> Key Specs</p>
                    <div class="item-text-specs">
                        <div class="item-list">
                            <p class="article">12.5" (16:9) LED</p>
                            <p class="article">Intel processor&reg;</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item-list">
                            <p class="article">0.53" thin</p>
                            <p class="article">4/8 GB memory</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <!-- Item 3 End-->

        </ul>
    </div>
    <script src=""></script>
</body>
```

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto');

* {box-sizing: border-box;}

body {background-color: #FFFFFF;}

.container {
    padding: 1rem 1rem;
    max-width: 1200px;
    min-width: 320px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;

}
li {
    padding: 1rem; 
    /*background: #F8F9FA;*/
    color: #202020;
    opacity: 0.9;
}

li:hover {
    box-shadow: 1px 2px 3px 0px rgba(25,25,25,0.6);
    opacity: 1;
    transition:all 0.5s ease;  
}


h1 {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: lighter;
    font-size: 2.5em;
    color: #202124;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: -20px;
    height: 25px;
    width: 100%;
}
h2 {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: lighter;
}
.subtext {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: lighter;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    color: #202124;
    text-align: center;         
}

.pricing {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: lighter;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    margin-top: 0em;
    color: grey;
}
p {
    color: #555;
    line-height: 2em;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    font-weight: bold;
}
img {
    width: 100%; margin-bottom:1.5rem; border-radius: 5px;
}

.item-specs {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bolder;
    padding: 0.8em 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
    color: black;
    margin-top: 2em;
    margin-bottom: -1em;
}


/* Flexbox Styling */

.item-list {
  display: flex; 
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
.item {
  flex: 100%;
  margin: 0 0 1.25rem;
}

.article {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.7em;
  font-weight: lighter;

}

@media (min-width: 36em) {

.item { 
  flex: 0 0 calc( 50% - 1.25rem / 2 );
  margin-left: 1.25rem;
}

 .item:nth-child(odd){ 
   margin-left: 0;
 }  

}

@media (min-width: 60em) {
.item {flex: 0 0 calc(100% / 3 - 0.875rem);
}

.item:nth-child(odd), item:nth-child(even) { 
    margin-left: 1.25rem;
}

 .item:nth-child(3n+1) { 
  margin-left: 0;} 
}
```

Comment: I think the easiest way (without using javascript) is to put a defined height on the <p> tag that contains the text "The first high performance Chromebook", "The power of a Chromebook." etc. You could probably use `.item-text p:nth-of-type(2){height: ...}`

Comment: thank you! yes it  works! Now I just have to fix the actual key specs because its  seems when it takes the 2 paragraph, it also took the whole key  specs. So I have extra spacing. I was thinking converting it into divs

Comment: Add flex-basis: 100%; to your item-list class. And display: flex; to your item class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to achieve this.

---

### Static

The easiest, but most fragile way would be to wrap the top section in a `<div>` determine the height of the tallest box, and set that as the `min-height` in CSS. But this runs into maintainability issues if the text is too long, or the boxes adjust width on different screen sizes.

**HTML**

```
<li class="item item1">
    <div class="item-intro">
        <img src="images/chromebookpro.jpg">
        <h2>Google Pixelbook</h2>
        <p class="pricing">Starting at $999</p>
        <p>The first high performance Chromebook with Google Assistent built in. Features a four-in-one design offering laptop, tablet, tent, and entertainment modes, an all day battery with fast charging, a sleek aluminum body, and an optional pen. </p>
    </div>
    <div class="item-text-specs">
        <p class="item-specs"> Key Specs</p>
        <div class="item-list">
            <p class="article">12.3" Quad HD LCD</p>
            <p class="article">Intel processor&reg;</p>
        </div>
        <div class="item-list">
            <p class="article">128/256/512 GB</p>
            <p class="article">8/16 GB memory</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

**CSS**

```
.item-intro {
    min-height: 300px;
}
```

---

### Dynamic - Pure CSS

Another option is to make two boxes for the top and bottom item description. Then using `flexbox`, you can make the heights automatically match each other. But this becomes complex for mobile responsiveness and will require the use of `order`. You could also use `grid` to achieve something similar.

**HTML**

```
<ul class="item-list">

    <!-- Item 1 Start-->
    <li class="item item1">
        <img src="images/chromebookpro.jpg">
        <div class="item-text">
            <h2>Google Pixelbook</h2>
            <p class="pricing">Starting at $999</p>
            <p>The first high performance Chromebook with Google Assistent built in. Features a four-in-one design offering laptop, tablet, tent, and entertainment modes, an all day battery with fast charging, a sleek aluminum body, and an optional pen. </p>
        </div>
    </li>

    <div class="item-text-specs item1">
        <p class="item-specs"> Key Specs</p>
        <div class="item-list">
            <p class="article">12.3" Quad HD LCD</p>
            <p class="article">Intel processor&reg;</p>
        </div>
        <div class="item-list">
            <p class="article">128/256/512 GB</p>
            <p class="article">8/16 GB memory</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Item 1 End-->


    <!-- Item 2 Start-->
    <li class="item item2">
        <img src="images/chromebookpro.jpg">
        <div class="item-text">
            <h2>Samsung Chromebook Pro</h2>
            <p class="pricing">Starting at $549</p>
            <p>The power of a Chromebook. The versatility of a tablet. A 360 degree rotating screen and an Intel&reg; Core&trade; M3 processor helps get things done. Write and create naturally with a built-in pen.</p>
        </div>
    </li>
    <div class="item-text-specs item2">
        <p class="item-specs"> Key Specs</p>
        <div class="item-list">
            <p class="article">12.3" Quad HD LCD</p>
            <p class="article">Intel processor&reg;</p>
        </div>
        <div class="item-list">
            <p class="article">32 GB eMMC</p>
            <p class="article">1 x 4 GB memory</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Item 2 End-->

    <!-- Item 3 Start-->
    <li class="item item3">
        <img src="images/chromebookpro.jpg">
        <div class="item-text">
            <h2>ASUS Chromebook Flip C302</h2>
            <p class="pricing">Starting at $499</p>
            <p>Flip between a high-performance Chromebook, a handy backlit tablet, and anything in between with a 360 degree hinge.</p>
        </div>
    </li>
    <div class="item-text-specs item3">
        <p class="item-specs"> Key Specs</p>
        <div class="item-list">
            <p class="article">12.5" (16:9) LED</p>
            <p class="article">Intel processor&reg;</p>
        </div>
        <div class="item-list">
            <p class="article">0.53" thin</p>
            <p class="article">4/8 GB memory</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Item 3 End-->

</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.item,
.item-text-specs {
  flex: 0 1 100%;
}

/* Only needed for desktop */
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .item-text-specs.item1 {
    order: 4;
  }
  .item-text-specs.item2 {
    order: 5;
  }
  .item-text-specs.item3 {
    order: 6;
  }
}
```

---

### Dynamic - JS

Final option would be to write a JavaScript snippet that loops through the top boxes, finds the tallest box, and applies that height to all boxes. You would have to modify your HTML to separate the top description in a `<div>` as outlined in the **Static** example. I am not going to write the Javascript because it would be time consuming, but it should be relatively simple. The most difficult feature will be triggering the height adjustment when the window size changes, if the width of the boxes changes as well. Because of this, it may be easier to use jQuery depending on your familiarity with Javascript.